# OpenGL VAO VBO resize

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

I have ran into an issue that uploading new content of a different size to the buffer causes VAO to behave unpredictably. Causing my object to look as if the buffer size was incorrectly set.

1) I generate VAO and VBO for an object

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao); // Generate 1 VAO
glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo); // Generate 1 VBO
```

2) Get location of uniform variables and attributes

3) Set the bindings like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo); // Bind VBO first
glBindVertexArray(_vao); // Bind VAO properties to VBO
{
    GLsizei packSize = DIM * sizeof(GLfloat) * 2;

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_position);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_position, DIM, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, packSize, (GLvoid*)0);

    // And so on ...
}
glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Unbind VBO
```

4) Then I load my data:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
                              _vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**The problem** starts when I try to load new data of a **different size**:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
                              _vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And my buffer size seem to remain the same.

Though, if I define and bind my vao to vbo again (like in 3-d step)

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vbo); 
glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
// glBindBuffer... See step 3
// ...
```

It works.

Is it possible to avoid recreating the new buffer?
What is prefered way of resizing it?

[Resize screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu16L.jpg)

Why it behaves such way?

I use *OpenGL version 4.2.0 Build 10.18.10.3379*

Comment: I need to upload more vertices to the buffer. If I call `glBufferData` it draws only part of the vertices, as the buffer size stay untouched

Comment: I attached screenshot. Any ideas why it could work wrong?

Comment: Maybe I need to update VAO somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> What is prefered way of resizing it?

The preferred way of resizing buffer objects is to *not resize them*. I'm being serious.

The OpenGL ARB created an [entire alternate way of allocating storage for buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage), for the *sole purpose* of making it impossible to reallocate them later. OK, if you want to be technical, the purpose of immutable storage is to allow persistent mapping, which requires immutability, but if they just wanted persistent mapped buffers, they could have restricted the new API to just those.

Figure out what the maximum size of your data will be (or whatever maximum you want to support), allocate that up front, and just whatever part you want to.

---

Technically, your code ought to work. By the standard, if you resize a buffer object, things that reference it ought to be able to see the resized storage. But since implementations don't want you to resize them, high-performance applications don't resize them. So that code is rarely tested in real applications, and bugs can linger for quite some time.

Just don't do it.

Comment: I have to resize my buffer by design. I have no idea, why it works so strange then

Comment: @kupihleba: Re-think your design. If the new size is smaller than the old one, then just use a smaller parameter in `glBufferSubData` and in `glDraw***` commands. If it's greater I'm sure you can slice your model into several buffers and use several `glDraw***`calls.